# My CASE WHEN SQL statement is incorrect

Tags: mysql

Can someone tell my why this isn't compiling?

```
select p.name, p.client_product_id, 
(case when c.ancestry is not null
then
  (select c1.title
    from catalogs c1
    where c1.id = c.ancestry) as catalog,
  c.title as subcatalog
else
  c.title as catalog
end),
image
from products p 
inner join product_catalogs pc on p.id = pc.product_id 
inner join catalogs c on c.id = pc.catalog_id 
inner join images i on i.imageable_id = p.id
where p.active = 1
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Looks like the `as catalog` should be placed after `end)` since that's where the column alias will be applied (as a result of the entire case expression)

Comment: But I can't recall ever attempting a subselect inside a `CASE` so I don't know if MySQL will permit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `CASE` expression is wrong, you can re-write your query like below; notice an extra `JOIN` have been added

```
select p.name, p.client_product_id, 
(case when c.ancestry is not null then c1.title else c.title end) as catalog,
image
from products p 
inner join product_catalogs pc on p.id = pc.product_id 
inner join catalogs c on c.id = pc.catalog_id 
inner join catalogs c1 on c1.id = c.ancestry //this one
inner join images i on i.imageable_id = p.id
where p.active = 1;
```

Comment: sorry I missed a line in my original post.  When `c.ancestry is not null` then I need `c1.title as catalog` AND `c.title as subcatalog`.  When `c.ancestry is null` then just `c.title as catalog`.

Comment: @mikeglaz, modify the case expression accordingly; you may need to another extra but aliasname has to singuler